# Import CSV File to Mysql Table Without Primary Key

Tags: java

im trying to import a csv file containing these columns:

**foreignKey, date, lobby**

so, mysql table should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Patient( 
foreignKey int not null, 
date datetime not null, 
lobby int not null, 
foreign key(foreignKey)references Foreign(Id));
```

as you noticed, my table does not have a primary key, I tried to add JPA entities 
to my project, but it does not recognize this tables due table does not have a PK.

Any advices about this issue on my code fellas?

kudos!

Comment: My advice is to add an autogenerated primary key to the table, and thus to your JPA entity.

Comment: What error do you have when importing csv file ?

Comment: it was not really needed to add a primary key, I used JDBC Driver instead JPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a primary key to the table with `auto_integer`

You should be able to import your CSV with `LOAD DATA INFILE`:

```
load data local infile 'myData.csv' 
into table Patient fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(foreignKey, date, lobby)
```

Make sure to remove headings from the CSV and change the delimiters as per your CSV file if necessary.

[LOAD DATA INFILE - MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

i had to use JDBC Driver to connect to the database, the primary key on the Foreign table was not really needed, so, I created generic repositories on each table on my database